# Screen Won't Log

Tags: linux, centos

I am using screen for some activities, which I want to have logged.

Basically I use: **screen -S server1** to create a screen.
Now, it "should" create a log file screenlog.0 - however, it does not.

I've tried using **screen -SL server1** but that won't help either.
I've also tried using pressing **<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>** in the screen, however that doesn't work either.

Any tips how to make it force create the screen log?

More info, if needed:

CentOS 6.3 64bit (Xen).
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you. I use `screen -dmSL` in a daily cron job (as root) and it creates `/root/screenlog.0` as expected. Are you nested within another screen?

Comment: Thank you! It actually worked. Also, I tried with two users - root & a non-SU account. But your solution worked, thanks a ton!

Comment: I've noticed that it only creates one log in total. I have 5 screens running, but only one of them gets logged, how will I go about fixing that?